# Subject omission in a compound sentence with both affirmative and negative sentences

Tags: sentence-construction, imperative-sentences

> These alerts **are** part of the testing process, **do not indicate** an
> actual emergency, and **do not require** any action at your end.

Is it grammatical to omit the subject in a compound sentence with both affirmative and negative sentences? I feel the second and third sentences are imperative.

Comment: Syntactically, it's fine. Stylistically, some people will probably say it would be better to re-state the subject before the *first* "polarity switch" (using negated do-support). Personally, I think that "stylistically weak" assessment applies even more strongly if you *start* with a negated assertion, then continue with non-negated elements:  *These alerts **do not** require any action at your end, **are** part of the testing process, and **are** for information only.* But that's all subjective, *matter of opinion*. It's an interesting point to raise, though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Does the compound sentence sound odd to your ear, a native speaker's ear?

Comment: I would say the example is a poor stylistic choice (not so much a grammar issue).  When I first began to read the sentence, I had to do a double-take, and read it again to check. That is never a good sign. The sentence is what I would call awkward rather than wrong.  I would prefer "These alerts, which are part of the testing process, do not . . . , and do not . . . "

Comment: @BillyKerr That rewrite sounds excellent to me too!

Comment: Also, you can make it punchier. Instead of "a part of the testing process" you can say "These alerts **are only a test.**... They do not .... "

Comment: You'll end up not seeing the wood for the trees, with stylistic recommendations ranging from *It's okay as it is (do nothing)* to *complete rewrite*. I suggest if the way you originally wrote it seemed "natural" to you (albeit with misgivings), a *minimal change* to resolve those misgivings is the easiest way to improve your English without having to seriously rethink the whole utterance. And that minimal change is simply to include ***they*** before ***do not indicate...*** (Personally, I'd include capitalized ***They,*** to start a new sentence, but commas are all the rage these days! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers :)

Comment: The second and third clauses are _not_ imperatives. The subject of all three verbs is _these alerts_. Personally, I don't have a problem with the sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that sentence has correct grammar. If the second and third parts were imperative sentences, they would all have to either be separated within the sentence with *conjunctions* like "so" or "and", or separated into separate sentences:

> These alerts are part of the testing process, so do not indicate an actual emergency, and do not require any action at your end.
> OR
> These alerts are part of the testing process. Do not indicate an actual emergency. Do not require any action at your end.

These two versions are nonsense of course, since those imperative commands don't make sense in the context, but demonstrate how we know the original sentence does not have any imperatives.

THAT SAID, the wording is awkward, and the reader would likely have to go back and read again to make sure they understood. It would be better phrased as two sentences:

> These alerts are part of the testing process. They do not indicate an actual emergency, and do not require any action at your end.